# is there an efficient way to retrieve a value associated to a key from all hashes in redis?

Tags: redis

Is there an efficient way to retrieve a value associated to a certain key from all hashes stored on Redis?

I'm using Redis to store hashes for taking advantage of the RediSearch module, but I also need to recover some of the values from those Hashes.

For example, I have an hash with those keys

```
"address", "state"
```

and I want to recover, for all the hashes, the value associated to address key

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly - you'd have to use `SCAN` to go through the keyspace (ideally giving all your hashes a common key prefix so you can use the `MATCH` option.  You'd also want to use the `TYPE` option to make sure you only get hashes back from the scan... For example if your hashes were in keys that all had a common prefix `record:` then you could do:

```
SCAN 0 MATCH record:* TYPE hash
```

Then you'd have to call `HGET` on each key returned to get the field.  This won't be very efficient as you incur the cost of the scan plus get hash get, although you could pipeline the hash gets to reduce the number of round trips to Redis a bit.

If you can use Redis Stack, you could use the search capability to build an index over your hashes with the `FT.CREATE` command.  Redis would then index your hashes and track changes to the indexed data automatically for you.  You could then use the `FT.SEARCH` command to write a more SQL like query to get the values back.

https://redis.io/commands/?group=search